# What is "quorum-manager" under Designation in GPFS Cluster Information?

Tags: linux, cluster

I get this block of information under my GPFS cluster information when I execute `/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/mmlscluster` and I can't find documentation on what the Designation actually means. Does `quorum-manager` for all servers mean that all 3 nodes are master/manager nodes?

```
 Node  Daemon node name       IP address     Admin node name        Designation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   someserver1.com        XX.XX.XX.XX    someserver1.com        quorum-manager
   2   someserver2.com        XX.XX.XX.XX    someserver2.com        quorum-manager
   3   someserver3.com        XX.XX.XX.XX    someserver3.com        quorum-manager
```

But I read here, [The GPFS cluster manager](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-scale/5.0.1?topic=functions-gpfs-cluster-manager), that:

> There is one GPFS™ cluster manager per cluster. The cluster manager is chosen through an election held among the set of quorum nodes designated for the cluster.

So what's the master-slave configuration I have for my GPFS cluster?

--- Edit---

I'll post what I have gathered in case it's useful

Designation definitions from [mmlscluster documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-scale/5.0.1?topic=reference-mmlscluster-command#mmlscluster) (still does not define `quorum-manager`; Thanks @Dani_l for the link in the comments)

> Designation, such as whether the node is any of the following:
>
> - quorum node - A node in the cluster that is counted to determine if a quorum exists. Members of a cluster use the quorum node to determine
>   if it is safe to continue I/O operations when a communications failure
>   occurs.
> - manager node - The file system node that provides the file system manager services to all of the nodes using the file system, including:
>   file system configuration, disk space allocation, token management,
>   and quota management.
> - snmp_collector node - The designated SNMP collector node for the cluster. The GPFS SNMP subagent runs on the designated SNMP collector
>   node.
> - gateway node - Ensures primary and Disaster Recovery cluster communication during failover.
> - perfmon node - Performance monitoring nodes collect metrics and performance information and sends the information to one or more
>   performance collection nodes.

I'm guessing that `quorum-manager` might mean that all 3 nodes are quorum nodes and all 3 *can* be manager nodes. In other words, `quorum-manager` does not indicate that a node is a manager node, but that it has the ability to be one.

To tell which one is the manager/master node, we have to execute a separate command `mmlsmgr -c` or `/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/mmlsmgr -c` to find out.

Would be glad for someone to confirm or refute this hypothesis!

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-scale/5.0.1?topic=reference-mmlscluster-command#mmlscluster you shouldn’t need more than one manager but should have multiple quorum nodes.

Comment: As for the title question- it’s 2 separate designations: a quorum node and also a file system manager node. The manager node is usually a quorum node, but that’s just a convention and not a requirement iirc.